# how to setting simple html dom with curl

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

hy i'using simple html dom for grabbing
and my quations is...

1 .How I can setting in simple html dom like

```
  "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER"<br>
  "CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT"<br>
  "CURLOPT_TIMEOUT"<br>
  "CURLOPT_USERAGENT"<br>
  "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER"<br>
  "CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS"<br>
```

2. how to setting specify many records in simple html dom when processing grabbing

for example i have code

```html
include "inc/simple_html_dom.php";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/');
foreach($items as $i => $post) {
    // get the img
    $img = $post->find('img', 0)->src;
 $url = $post->find('a', 0)->href;
}
```

Comment: im really not sure what you're asking for, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: thanks for answer iamde_coder but I mean, I have using simple html dom but not understand how to setting function curl in simple html dom like "CURLOPT_TIMEOUT"

Comment: you mean by doing something like: `$ch = curl_init();` `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);` ??

Comment: yes thanks but when i'm implantation not work for me this for new my code :$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'http:/exmple/');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 5);

Comment: curl and simple_html_dom are separate libraries. They have nothing to do with each other.